# epoch время в секундах ковертовать в PST (Pacific STandart Time) время

Tags: python, unixtimestamp, timezone

Есть значение времени в секундах например 1471282495000 как перевести его в читаемый PST формат?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить информацию о часовой зоне, можно использовать [`pytz` модуль (чистый Питон)](http://pythonhosted.org/pytz/):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz # pip install pytz
>>> millis = 1471282495000
>>> str(datetime.fromtimestamp(millis*1e-3, pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')))
'2016-08-15 10:34:55-07:00'
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло, работает как надо))

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1471282495000 / 1000)
print(date)
```

Comment: это возвращает локальное время как наивный `datetime` объект 1- локальная часовая зона может отличаться от Pacific Standard Time  2- теряется информация о часовом поясе